# Launch Discord app in a specific channel (Linux)

Tags: terminal, discord

Can I launch Linux Discord app in a specific channel using command line? I can launch the app with `Discord`, but have no idea if I can add some options to do what I want.

In browser, I can use the domain with `/channel/<channel_id>` to reach a specific channel.